# Django : debugging templatetags

Tags: django, django-templates

How on earth do people debug Django templatetags?

I created one, based on a working example, my new tag looks the same to me as the existing one. But I just get a

```
'my_lib' is not a valid tag library: Could not load template library from django.templatetags.my_lib, No module named my_lib
```

I know that this is probably because of something failing when defining the lib. But how do I see what's going on?

What do you use to debug this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like Django can't find the python file your template tag is defined in. Django finds custom tags in a folder named templatetags in your apps folders.

So if you have an app called Books, and you're calling `{% load book_tags %}` in your template, your Books app folder should look something like this:

- Books

  - `__init__.py`
  - views.py
  - models.py
  - templatetags

    - `__init__.py`
    - book_tags.py

Make sure that `__init__.py` file is in templatetags.

Comment: the Books app must also be in the INSTALLED_APPS setting. The template tags loader thingy looks through each 'templatetags' directory in each installed app from top to bottom.

Comment: Thanks guys. Good advice. Actually I found the problem : my file didn't have the same name as the library being included. Stupidly I assumed that the name in the {% load .. %} was the name of the app.